# Query for each publisher where authors > 1

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

These are my tables, i'm struggling to formulate a query for doing the following:

For each publisher with more than one author, get the publishers name, location and average cost of the books they sell.

I'm thinking i need a SELECT COUNT(authorName) but i'm at a loss as to the JOIN of the two queries any assistance?

EDIT:

```
SELECT publisherName, COUNT(authorName) AS noAuthors FROM Book GROUP BY publisherName;
```

Will return my authorCount per publisher, just the join now

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: No, going over an old paper i did badly on

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT publisherName, COUNT( DISTINCT authorName ) AS noAuthors, Publisher.location, AVG( Book.Cost ) AS avgCost
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Publisher ON Publisher.name = publisherName
GROUP BY publisherName
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT authorName ) >1;
```

Figured it out in the end, probably ways of optimizing but it works!

Creates:

[image]
<sub>(source: [joescott.me](http://share.joescott.me/9930e4.png))</sub>

Comment: As I understand you want select "each publisher with more than one author", so it seems you should add for this query: "HAVING noAuthors > 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.publishername,
       p.location,
       count(distinct b.authorname) as noauthors,
       avg(b.cost) as avg_cost
  from book b
  join publisher p
    on b.publishername = p.name
 group by b.publishername, p.location
having count(distinct b.authorname) > 1
```

Something to point out:
You have to count distinct authors, count(authorname) > 1 will potentially include publishers who have 2+ books with the same author, but no books with other authors. The above limits the results to publishers who have books with 2 or more unique authors, which is what you said was desired, in your question.

**Fiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45019/1/0

**Output:**

```
| PUBLISHERNAME | LOCATION | NOAUTHORS | AVG_COST |
|---------------|----------|-----------|----------|
|     TechBooks |   London |         2 |     32.5 |
```

Notice how BudgetBooks is excluded. They have 2 books, but both are with the same author. If you did not do a distinct count, they would be erroneously included.